# Using ping on multiple interfaces on a NIC

Tags: networking, ping, testing, networkcard

I have two systems and each have a NIC with two ethernet ports. One system has a verified NIC card, but the other has a NIC which has to be verified.

I use `ping` to verify whether the interfaces on the NIC card is functioning correctly.

Why does each interface have to be on a different subnet for `ping` to work?

For example:

```
System 1:  eth0 (10.0.0.1), eth1 (10.0.1.1) -->This NIC is tested good
                  ^                ^
                  |                |
                  V                V
System 2:  eth0 (10.0.0.2), eth1 (10.0.1.2) -->This NIC is being tested
```

In this setup, `eth0` on `System 1` is connected to `eth0` on `System 2`.
And `eth1` on `System 1` is connected to `eth1` on `System 2`.  I am using submet mask of `255.255.255.0`.

So on `System 2`, I would do the following:

```
$ ping -I eth0 -c 100 -qA 10.0.0.1
$ ping -I eth1 -c 100 -qA 10.0.1.1
```

Why couldn't I have this setup though?

```
System 1:  eth0 (10.0.0.1), eth1 (10.0.0.2) -->This NIC is tested good
                  ^                ^
                  |                |
                  V                V
System 2:  eth0 (10.0.0.3), eth1 (10.0.0.4) -->This NIC is being tested
```

And then do:

```
$ ping -I eth0 -c 100 -qA 10.0.0.1
$ ping -I eth1 -c 100 -qA 10.0.0.2
```

What is it about having a host with multiple interfaces?

```
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Comment: what do you want to ask? `ping` still works even if your interfaces in the same subnet.

Comment: `netstat -rn | grep default`

Comment: @Gnouc : You will not be able to `ping` in the second setup of using ip address (10.0.0.1-4).  `ping` will only work in the first case.

Comment: @Warwick what is that supposed to do?

Comment: @user1527227: Is your two host in the same network or not?

Comment: @Gnouc answer is yes

Comment: @user1527227: Your two system is connected through a switch or a router?

Comment: Switch... just so we're clear: in addition to my setup in question stem, system 1 has interface on motherboard with ip `192.168.1.169` mask `255.255.252.0` and system 2 has ip `192.168.2.156` mask `255.255.252.0`. thx!

Comment: I suspect that what happens in that case is that your ping request from system 1 is sent through the interface specified, but is returned via a different route and interface based on how the default route is set up on system 2. What are your systems running?

Comment: `ubuntu 14-04` but when you specify `ping -I eth0` doesn't it force route through that interface only and avoid other routes?

Comment: It will force system 1 to use that interface, yes, but system 2 won't know about that. System 2 will return via whatever route is configured on it.

Comment: Oh... so maybe that's why when its on a different subnet this problem is solved because then there is only one route to send and receive on a particular interface?  Perhaps someone could verify this in answer below?  Thank you all

Comment: If you have a different network configured for eth1 on systems 1 and 2, then by default, any packets for that network will use those interfaces, rather than eth0. When they are all on the same network though, they will get sent via the default route unless there is a specific route specified on system 2 that says send packets to 10.0.0.2 via 10.0.0.4

Comment: i see.  I added the routing table in the question stem.  there doesn't seem to be a default route so i dont know how that would work.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is the default route.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15502/discussion-between-warwick-and-user1527227).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a different network configured for eth1 on systems 1 and 2, then by default, any packets for that network will use those interfaces, rather than eth0. When they are all on the same network though, they will get sent via the default route unless there is a specific route specified on system 2 that says send packets to 10.0.0.2 via 10.0.0.4.

To view the routing table on system 2, run

```
netstat -rn
```

If no specific route is set up for this network, then the default route will be used.

To change that behaviour, you would run on system 2 a command similar to:

```
route add -host 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.4
```

(Sorry, I don't use Ubuntu so the syntax may be different. Perhaps someone can verify and edit this answer if required.)